# Localization does not work anymore under iOS 9 / iOS 9.0.1

Tags: localization, translation, ios9

Since I create iOS Apps I use the following code to translate / localize my apps:

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([language isEqualToString:@"de"]) {
    // localized language
}
else { //base language
}
```

But since the update to iOS 9 this code does not work anymore.
All my apps are now in English.

Neither the apps I already have in the app store, nor the apps I run in the Simulator are localized anymore.

It would be great if you could tell me how I have to translate my code programmatically in iOS 9.

Comment: What do you get for `language`?

Comment: I always get "en".
Actually I run the app in german, so I should get: "de".

Comment: Maybe it is related to the following bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017981/ios-localization-doesnt-work-with-more-than-63-files?newreg=5def7e334c554377be788b1ce2eace3e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem.

If I use the following code the localization works under iOS 9.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations];
NSString *language = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([language isEqualToString:@"de"]){
            // localization
        }
        else {
            //base language
        }
```

I hope that will help some of you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a category class for Localizing strings for specified language which automatically detect the current language and localize the same.

Create a category class with Name 
RunTimeLanguage

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSBundle (RunTimeLanguage)
#define NSLocalizeString(key, comment) [[NSBundle mainBundle] runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
- (NSString *)runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.h"

@implementation NSBundle (RunTimeLanguage)
- (NSString *)runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSString *StrCurrentLang = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:StrCurrentLang ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle *languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString *localizedString=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:key table:nil];
    return localizedString;
}
@end
```

You can directly access the localized value by using below statement.

```
NSLocalizeString(@"yourText", nil)
```