# iOS Localization Doesn't Work with More Than 63 Files

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, ios9

On iOS 9, the localization is not working well when more than 63 localization files are added. If you have minus than 63 files, the translation can work correctly, but when more than 63 files are added the Xcode doesn't call the correct language file, always calling base.

On my GitHub example project (https://github.com/munhra/iOSLocalizationExample), there are 64 localization files added to Xcode. If run the project, Xcode doesn't call the corresponding device language. 
If a translation file is removed, we can run the Xcode again e check that the application language is correctly, based on the device language settings.

Comment: do you mean 63 localizable.string files to support 63 languages ?

Comment: Yes, I mean 63 localizable.string files

Comment: Is the language you've removed a supported language?

Comment: could you please tell us, why you would like to have 64 files? Apple does support around 40 languages

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue which is currently being investigated. Please file a bug report with your Xcode+iOS SDK version at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)